# Why doesn't my image show in a jsp? [confused]

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-tool-suite

I'm new to Spring MVC and the Spring framework in general and I'm trying to learn it.

I did a small "hello world" project using the Spring Tool Suite and encountered a strange issue. So I started a new Spring Project and chose Spring MVC Project. I created a controller and a view jsp page to display a hello page. All is working fine. There is no problem here.
Then I decided to include a picture in my jsp page. I copied a picture to the "webapp/resources" folder and put an img tag like this in my view page (whose path is "webapp/WEB-INF/views/hello.jsp"). The tag looks like this :

When I run the application and go to my view page it doesn't show the image in STS internal browser or in my regular browser. I tried to view the source of the page from my browser and the source does have the img tag but for some reason it's not shown.

I tried to put the image directly in "webapp/WEB-INF/views" along with my jsp file and changed the tag to this:

but still no success. Finally, I blamed this on my inexpirience with creating jsp's and tried to open up my regular Eclipse IDE (i.e. one different from STS) and created a Dynamic Web Project where I inserted the tag into a jsp file and copied the picture in one of the project's subfolders. I ran the project and now it works ; the picture is shown.

Why is happening this? Why it works in a regular web project and doesn't work in a Spring MVC Project? Thank you for your time and I appreciate if you help me!

Comment: Try to open the browser developer tools and under the Network tab you will see the request for your image and the status.

Comment: Please share the request which is failing

Comment: The status is "404 not found"
I took a screenshot of my browser here
http://img802.imageshack.us/img802/3041/9tt5.jpg

Comment: I tried to edit my url path to the image inside the img tag and if I give an url relative to the project folder it works.
Now my img tag looks like this:

<img src="/helloworld/resources/Hellraider.jpg" > 
I don't know why it doesn't work with a relative path from the jsp file as I used before but it doesn't matter that much now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: just a guess. If you copied the image into eclipse workspace using some external copy, eclipse doesn't know and you need to "refresh" the eclipse navigator or package explorer view. Then the image will be visible in eclipse and eclipse can publish it to your webapp.

Comment: Although it's an interesting point of view, unfortunately it's not the case here, as I've tried to refresh the project afterwards and give it a go and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I tried to put the image directly in "webapp/WEB-INF/views"
```

The image shouldn't be under `/WEB-INF/` because this folder is not accessibile outside the app. It should be under `webapp`, e.g.`webapp/resources/myLogo.png`
and then use it like : `resources/myLogo.png` in the `img src`.

Answer (score 0):

jsp files are not regular html file.
you should use `<c:url />` tag to make sure your resources path are computed from the root of your project:

```
<img src='<c:url value="/img/mylogo.png"/>' class="logo"/>
```

where mylogo.png is inside WebContent/img/